# ¿Como mandar un alert de javascript desde una clase .cs en c# ASP.NET?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

necesito ayuda!!.... Les explico, estoy desarrollando una plataforma web en C# ASP.NET con Visual Studio donde en alguna parte del codigo necesito mandar un alert con una cadena desde una clase .cs. eh probado usar el  ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript pero me da un error :(

El método es invocado desde otro metodo y solo debo mostrar en el alert la cadena que recibe.
Aqui el codigo,

```
namespace DATA.UTIL
{
  public  class TituloDescarga   
    {

public void decodeBase64(string cadenaBase64, string numeroDeLotes)
        {
            string script = string.Format("alert('"+ cadenaBase64 +"');");
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", script, true);

        }
   }
}
```

Este es el erro que me da :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Eh utilizado tambien el ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBloc, pero me salta un error que no se a que se deba :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui mis importaciones

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El tema es que esta funcionalidad no se usa desde una libreria propia, sino que debes hacerlo desde un `.aspx.cs` o sea desde el codigo de un `web form`.

Entonces defines la class como ser

```
namespace DATA.UTIL
{
    public class TituloDescarga   
    {
        public string decodeBase64(string cadenaBase64, string numeroDeLotes)
        {
            //aqui codigo
            return "string decode";
        }
   }
}
```

Y en la pagina web aspx lo usarias

```
public class WebPage1 : Page
{
    
    public void button1_Click(...)
    {
        TituloDescarga t = new TituloDescarga();
        string cadenaBase64 = t.decodeBase64("xx", "xx");
        
        string script = string.Format("alert('{0}');", cadenaBase64);
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "alert", script, true);
    }
}
```

Es en la pagina donde usas esa funcionalidad no en la class, ese `this` que usa el `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` es la instancia de web form

Answer (score 0):

Vayamos por partes,...
1.- `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript` the name does not exist in the current context, o dicho de otra manera, ClientScript no es un objeto previamente declarado, tienes dos opciones:

1.1 declarar un objeto de manera local y llamarlo, (opcion buena), o pasarlo por parámetro a tu función.
1.2 declarar el objeto como variable global, (opcion mala).

Tienes un ejemplo de como se usa en https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript?view=netframework-4.8

2.- can't convert... este es un error de tipo casting que te falta por hacer o le estas pasando el parametro equivocado, por lo visto this apunta a un objeto DATA.Util.TituloDeDescarga, mientras que necesitas pasarle uno de la clase System.Web.UI.Page. Tu problema es que parece seguir https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerclientscriptblock?view=netframework-4.8, pero no puedo afirmarlo al no ver todo el codigo, si te fijas, en el ejemplo this apunta a una pagina web y por lo visto tu estas apuntando a otro tipo de objeto, con lo cual, no te puedo decir mas, porque no veo el resto del codigo,